# Xamarin Forms - How to animate modal from right to left using PushModalAsync?

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to animate modal from right to left using PushModalAsync in Xamarin Forms?

By default, the animation is from bottom to top.

Comment: Maybe can implement modal view custom animation with DependencyService to invoke push and pop methods.

Comment: Have you tried using a `NavigationPage`, you can push a page (not modally) and it will add it with an animation across screen.  This is the default across screen navigation you see in the majority of mobile apps.